# Error handling in swagger-express-mw

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I have the following code in my app.js

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
   console.log("Web Server started.");

   if (err) { throw err; }

   // install middleware
   swaggerExpress.register(app);
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
     console.log('caught it!');
     dosomething();
   });
   var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
   app.listen(port);

});
```

And my controller hello_world.js

```
function hello(req, res) {
    throw new Error('my error!');  
}
```

When i start the app and browser to  http://localhost:10010/hello, this returns a 500 response with my error message as expected. However, the error handling middleware didn't get called at all. Any ideas?

Comment: It is important that the error handler appears *after* `swaggerExpress.register()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you remove the default fitting from `default.yaml`, it will work.

- onError: json_error_handler